# LWJGL - texture.bind not having enough space

Tags: java, lwjgl

When I try to bind a texture to a sphere in LWJGL the window does not respond for a about 30 seconds. Then a error appears say java heap space. I tried adding more space to java but it still didn't work. 
This is the code for the sphere and texture:

```
GL11.glEnable(GL11.GL_TEXTURE_2D);               

GL11.glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);   

GL11.glEnable(GL11.GL_BLEND);

Texture earthTexture = TextureLoader.getTexture("JPG",
        ResourceLoader.getResourceAsStream(earthPath));
//enable and bind the texture
earthTexture.bind();
Sphere earth = new Sphere();
earth.setDrawStyle(GLU.GLU_FILL);
earth.setTextureFlag(true);
earth.setNormals(GLU.GLU_SMOOTH);
earth.draw(2.3f, 25, 25);
```

This is the full class:

```
package com.game.planets;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;

import org.lwjgl.opengl.Display;
import org.lwjgl.opengl.GL11;
import org.lwjgl.util.glu.GLU;
import org.lwjgl.util.glu.Sphere;
import org.newdawn.slick.opengl.Texture;
import org.newdawn.slick.opengl.TextureLoader;

public class EarthPlanet {
    public static String earthPath = "src/com/game/planets/textures/earth.jpg";
    static Texture earthTexture;
    public static void renderEarth(){

    earthTexture = loadTexture("earth");

    GL11.glMatrixMode(GL11.GL_PROJECTION);
    GL11.glLoadIdentity();
    GL11.glMatrixMode(GL11.GL_MODELVIEW);

    GL11.glEnable(GL11.GL_TEXTURE_2D);  

    GL11.glClear(GL11.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    earthTexture.bind();
    Sphere earth = new Sphere();
    earth.setDrawStyle(GLU.GLU_FILL);
    earth.setTextureFlag(true);
    earth.setNormals(GLU.GLU_SMOOTH);
    earth.draw(2.3f, 25, 25);

    earthTexture.release();
}

private static Texture loadTexture(String key){
    try {
        return TextureLoader.getTexture("JPG", 
                new FileInputStream(new File("src/com/game/planets/textures/" + key+ ".jpg")));
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing, you are reloading the resource every time you draw to the screen?

Load the resource once and store it to a property/var. Then draw that preloaded var every time.

```
package com.game.planets;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;

import org.lwjgl.opengl.Display;
import org.lwjgl.opengl.GL11;
import org.lwjgl.util.glu.GLU;
import org.lwjgl.util.glu.Sphere;
import org.newdawn.slick.opengl.Texture;
import org.newdawn.slick.opengl.TextureLoader;

public class EarthPlanet {
    public static String earthPath = "src/com/game/planets/textures/earth.jpg";
    static Texture earthTexture;

    public EarthPlanet()
    {
        earthTexture = loadTexture("earth");    
    }

    public static void renderEarth(){

    GL11.glMatrixMode(GL11.GL_PROJECTION);
    GL11.glLoadIdentity();
    GL11.glMatrixMode(GL11.GL_MODELVIEW);

    GL11.glEnable(GL11.GL_TEXTURE_2D);  

    GL11.glClear(GL11.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    earthTexture.bind();
    Sphere earth = new Sphere();
    earth.setDrawStyle(GLU.GLU_FILL);
    earth.setTextureFlag(true);
    earth.setNormals(GLU.GLU_SMOOTH);
    earth.draw(2.3f, 25, 25);

    earthTexture.release();
}

private static Texture loadTexture(String key){
    try {
        return TextureLoader.getTexture("JPG", 
                new FileInputStream(new File("src/com/game/planets/textures/" + key+ ".jpg")));
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
}
```

Comment: It gave me this error:Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at com.game.main.GameWindow.gameLoop(GameWindow.java:108)
 at com.game.main.GameWindow.main(GameWindow.java:31)

Comment: I don't know what the GameWindow class looks like

Comment: Make sure you called the init() method btw.

Comment: @D.White thanks for posting the full class. Modified my response.